# Snowflake - Possible to create temporary table within a table/view Creation?

Tags: sql, oracle, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to create a view within Snowflake and within that view's dll I am trying to create a temporary table as I need to filter the data down a bit first to make it work as expected (I am migrating from Oracle SQL).

```
With DT1 as (select * from CPDD.DRRAW.EXTABLE1
            limit 100);

Create or replace view CPDD.DRRAW.TEST11 as 
(select * from DT1
limit 10)
```

I cannot seem to get the temporary table to actual work though as I keep getting 'unexpected create' error. Is it even possible to have a temporary table within a table/view DLL?

Ultimately, the reason I need something like this is because in Oracle SQL I have a NVL portion within the select statement and when migrating to Snowflake, I am getting 'Unsupported Subquery' error.

```
Select MAINTBL.ATT1, MAINTBL.ATTR2, 
NVL (
(SELECT cosa.av1
FROM CPDD.DRRAW.ATRVL1 cosa
WHERE     cosa.ATT_NM = 'MYDE'
AND cosa.OBJ_NM = OPN.ON),
(SELECT csoa.av1
FROM CPDD.DRRAW.ATRVL1 cosa
WHERE     cosa.ATT_NM = 'MYDE'
AND cosa.OBJ_NM = 'DEFLT'))
MYDE 
FROM CPDD.DRRAW.MAINTBL
```

Comment: You need to put the CTE within the CREATE statement

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, the `CTE` portion needs to come after `create` statement

```
create or replace temporary table xxxx as

with cte as 

(select ..
 from ...) 


select * 
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
create temporary table testtemp (a number);

Create or replace view testtemp_v as
(select * from testtemp
limit 1);
```

or

```
create or replace temporary table testtemp as
with DT1 as 
(select * from testtemp) 
select * 
from DT1;
```

Try them!